# How to fix TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable and an .append that isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the module that will input a two-dimensional array containing employee names and their corresponding salaries. 
Here the program is only taking one input and moving on instead of adding more inputs until the user types in "*". How do I fix this?

```
salary = []
names = []

def floatInput():
    done = False
    while not done:
        nameIn = input("Please enter the employee name or * to finish: ")
        salaryIn = input("Please enter the salary in thousands for " + nameIn + ": ")
        try:
            salaryIn = float(salaryIn)            
        except:
            print("Program was expecting a positive integer or floating point number!")
        if nameIn == "*":
           done = True
        else:
            salary.append(salaryIn)
            names.append(nameIn)
        return salary
        return names
```

Calling the float Input function

```
floatInput()
```

here I use a for loop to print and iterate through the list of names and salaries.

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    print(names[i] + ", " + str(salary[i]))
```

Here I find the mean of the salaries.

```
def salaryMean():
    mean = sum(salary) / float(len(salary))
    print("The mean of the salaries is: " + str(mean))
    return mean
```

Calling the salary mean Function

```
salaryMean()
```

here I convert the salary to thousands.

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    salary = salary[i] * 1000
print(salary)
```

Here I display all emplpyees who earn within a range of $5,000 from the mean
This is where I am getting the

```
"TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"
```

and it points to the line

```
"if salary[x] >= (mean - 5000) and salary[x] <= (mean + 500):"
```

.... How do I fix this?

```
def displayNames():
    done = False
    x = 0
    while not done:
        if done:
            break
        if salary[x] >= (mean - 5000) and salary[x] <= (mean + 5000):
            print(salary[x])
        x += 1
        if x > len(salary):
            done = True
```

Calling the display name Function.

```
displayNames()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your `.append` issue (also your second `return` statement is never going to execute, see below on how to return both lists):

Your loop isn't continuing is because you're returning inside the loop, thus terminating the function. Move your `return` statement outside of the loop (single unindent).

```
while not done:
    # do stuff
return salary, names
```

To fix your `TypeError` I think the problem is here:

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    salary = salary[i] * 1000 # Up to this point salary is a list, here it turns into the ith value of the list multiplied by 1000
print(salary)
```

Instead, replace that entire for loop with:

```
salary = [s*1000 for s in salary]
for s in salary:
    print(s) # This should now print the multiplied salaries.
```

Some other issues - you have two `return` statements followed by one another - the function will finish executing after the first return, and never execute the return below that one; if you want to return both `salary` and `names` use `return names, salary` (and maybe rename `salary` to `salaries` so that people can easily tell that it's a bunch of salaries, not just one).